# Fourier Series of $f(x)=e^x$ on $[0,\pi)$ as a function of period $\pi$

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-series, alternative-proof

Can you tell me what you get? I've tried computing it, I've got some result but I don't think it's right since I need to use it for something else and it doesn't work at all...
What exactly I'm trying to do is to find a infinite sum corresponding to $coth(\pi/2)$, do you see anything?

Thank you!

what I get:

$\exp(x) \sim  \dfrac{2\sinh(\pi/2)}{\pi}+ \sum \left[\tfrac{4(-1)^n \sinh(\pi/2)}{8n^2+\pi}\cos(2nx) - \tfrac{8n(-1)^n \sinh(\pi/2)}{8n^2+\pi}\sin(2nx)\right]$

That seems totally wrong...

Comment: Try writing your result. Just put the result in dollar signs and the site will render it for you.

Comment: I'll try editing, yes

Comment: As I said before, put your result in dollar signs and use standard latex commands to make it readable. It is not readable as it is now.

Comment: I've figured it out, it's a lot better now

Comment: Over what interval are you computing the series?  It is not clear from your question.

Comment: The function f(x) is defined on [0,pi), I'm guessing it calls an even extension?

Comment: I need an indication, please :/